# PrimeFaces <p:tree>: how to save tree state between refreshes?

Tags: jsf, tree, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces JSF library, and I have a tree where each node is a checkbox:

```
<p:tree selectionMode="checkbox"...>
```

This tree represents some files, and it is dynamicaly refreshed (polled) every 5 seconds since the files/nodes can be added or removed:

```
<p:poll interval="5" update="treeId"... />
```

User can select files via tree node checkboxes. Selected nodes are saved in an array of TreeNodes:

```
<p:tree selection="#{BackingBean.selectedNodes}"...>
```

Where selectedNodes is defined as:

```
private TreeNode[] selectedNodes;
```

The problem is: since the tree is constantly being refreshed (every 5 sec), I loose the tree state! What user has checked becomes unchecked again.

How would I keep the tree state remembered between 5-sec refreshes?

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using JSF 2:**

Make your backing bean `@ViewScoped`:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BackingBean {
    ...
}
```

**If you are using JSF 1.2:**

Use component [a4j:keepAlive](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_keepAlive.html) from Richfaces:

```
<a4j:keepAlive bean="BackingBean" />
```

You also have an option to use [Tomahawk's saveState](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_saveState.html) (with the Tomahawk's version appropriate for your project), to put only the selectedNodes in the view:

```
<t:saveState value="#{BackingBean.selectedNodes}" />
```

Just put Tomahawk and its dependencies in the `WEB-INF/lib`, register the filter in your web.xml and the namespace on your `.xhtml` page and you're good to go.

Comment: No. :-( My code doesn't work when I change the bean to view scoped; I need to do some major changes to make vies scoped work, and right now I have no time. Might there be another solution to the problem?

Comment: well, you can try to use `t:saveState` to save in the view only the tree of selectedNodes, I will update my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: What a bad moment to go back to Tomahawk: we just discarded all Tomahawk dependencies and completely removed Tomahawk from the project and are now using exclusively PrimeFaces. Does it make sense to again link the whole library, this time only because of this issue?

Comment: I see... Well, if I were you, I would make it work in the view scope.

Comment: Could not use ViewScoped bean since it required all objects to be serializable, and this is not possible in my code. So, ViewScoped is definitely a no go for me.